# Finding best linear predictor

Tags: predictor

I am given the model $Y_i=\alpha_0+\beta_0 X_i+\epsilon_0$, where $i=1,2,...,n$, $X_i$ are fixed numbers and $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2).$ I am also given that $\sigma^2$ and the parameters $(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ for $E(Y_i)=\alpha_0+\beta_0 X_i$ are unknown.

I have to estimate $(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ using $(\alpha^*,\beta^*)$ which are found by minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\alpha-\beta X_i)^2.$

To find $\alpha^*$, I set $\frac{d}{d\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\alpha-\beta X_i)^2=0$ and got that $\alpha^*=\widehat{Y}-\beta^* \widehat{X}$, where $\widehat{Y}=\frac{Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n}{n}$ and $\widehat{X}=\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}$.

However I am having a hard time finding $\beta^*$. Here is my process and where I get stuck:
$\frac{d}{d\beta}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\alpha-\beta X_i)^2=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d}{d\beta}(Y_i-\alpha-\beta X_i)^2=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(Y_i-\alpha-\beta X_i)=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i X_i-\alpha X_i-\beta X_i^2)=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i X_i-(\widehat{Y}-\beta \widehat{X}) X_i-\beta X_i^2)=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i X_i-\widehat{Y} X_i+\beta \widehat{X} X_i-\beta X_i^2)=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i X_i-\widehat{Y} X_i+\beta (\widehat{X} X_i-X_i^2))=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i X_i-\widehat{Y} X_i+\beta (\widehat{X} X_i-X_i^2))=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n \beta (\widehat{X} X_i-X_i^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n(\widehat{Y} X_i-Y_i X_i)$

$\beta^* =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(\widehat{Y} X_i-Y_i X_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n(\widehat{X} X_i-X_i^2)}$

However, $\beta^*$ should equal $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\widehat{X})Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\widehat{X})^2}$.

Could someone please explain what went wrong? Thank you.

Ps I am sorry for any mistakes in typing the given information, I am not too familiar with the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remark: The common notation for sample average of $X$ is $\bar{X}$.

Notice that since $\sum_{i=1}^n (\bar{X}-X_i)=0$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{X}(\bar{X}-X_i)=0$

\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n (\bar{X}X_i-X_i^2)&=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\bar{X}-X_i) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\bar{X}-X_i) -\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{X}(\bar{X}-X_i) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})(\bar{X}-X_i)\\
&=- \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2\end{align}

Similar simplification can be performed for the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are just being asked to find the proof for a simple linear regression model. As far as where you went wrong,

You made a couple mistakes at the beginning. But I found [this](https://www.amherst.edu/system/files/media/1287/SLR_Leastsquares.pdf) online and it should answer your question. Sorry for not typing it myself just trying to save time. If you need further explanation for why or how this works let me know.